# Are declaration files necessary when writing a typescript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

Do I need to generate typescript declaration files (and associated javascript) when publishing a typescript library?

Say I have a library (`foo`) with a top level `index.ts`:

```
export class LibraryClass
{
...
}
```

And then in my `bar` application, I write:

```
import { LibraryClass } from "foo";
```

Should this work even if I install the `foo` library in my `node_modules` directory? It is working for me currently linking the two repositories locally with `yarn link`, but I've been informed that it won't work once I publish the package and `yarn add` it - which makes no sense to me.

The library will be used solely in typescript projects, so it seems like it *should* be possible to eschew `tsc` and just import the types directly.

Comment: When you publish a "typescript library", you should really be publishing the javascript generated by the compiler, *as well as* the typescript declaration files. If you publish the raw typescript *source*, it won't work at runtime since you'll be trying to import typescript files and running those (which will likely lead to runtime errors because typescript is not valid javascript).

Comment: but why can't `tsc` just generate all the javascript it needs to when it compiles the application *using* the typescript library?

Comment: Presumably you would be excluding `node_modules` in your tsconfig, so it simply *wouldn't* try to compile any typescript files in the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Also, what if the library was developed using a different configuration than the one you are using? It might cause a lot of errors...

Comment: ok, that makes sense. but still, it seems a bit convoluted that there's no way to use typescript directly across a package boundary.

Comment: Not really. Just think about TypeScript as a build tool, like webpack or other bundlers. It's a step you have to do before shipping your product.